# Search is not working in a site. It is one of the multisite. Other sites are working

Tags: search, solr

I am using drupal 7 solr search module for search.While searching am receiving an error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." and css is not applied.In log messages I can see two errors 
1. ApAche Tomcat The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect
2. ApAche Tomcat The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect in DrupalApacheSolrService->checkResponse() (line 368 of/data/www/drupal/factory/sites/all/modules/search/apachesolr/Drupal_Apache_Solr_Service.php).

Solutions Tried
1. Reindexed site
2.ran the cron
3.Cleared cache
4.Indexed site
Could anyone say some solutions.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Need to add another point when reindexing am getting this error too SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null.. while running cron receiving this error

Comment: while running cron receiving this error no schema type for..